# Magento 2.2: How to display price block on product detail page in a custom theme

Tags: magento2, price, sku

I want to display the **price and SKU in the product detail page**. I've set **luma** as a **parent theme**. I am getting SKU under **product-info-price** div on frontend but not getting price. here is my layout file `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.msrp" before="product.price.final">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">msrp_price</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">configured_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

            </referenceContainer>


            <move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.review" />


            <referenceContainer name="product.info.sku" remove="false" />
```

Comment: your above code having `price_type_code` key two times, which is seems wrong.